# Some people got is "a possible malware" opening my site?

Tags: web-hosting, certbot

I tried to show js problem at my https://streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl/ site
But I got a feedback from one of users :

```
My connection block that site ^^ 
The security system of the network operator blocks me saying that it is "a possible malware" –
```

service

```
sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl
```

shows :

```
 streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl resolves to 18.198.221.45 Server Type: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) The certificate should be trusted by all major web browsers (all the correct intermediate certificates are installed). The certificate was issued by Let's Encrypt. The certificate will expire in 6 days. The hostname (streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl) is correctly listed in the certificate.
```

I run manually :

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

after that I read :
The certificate will expire in 66 days

Could you please to run my site and say if you have any problems opening it ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/f07ad9409e7b60633952021af9292753cc142f2a5675055fdbb19f8b563e0132/detection

Comment: Thanks! Which steps have I to take ? If it some bad code inside of my site ?  Or something wrong in ubuntu 20/apache/mysql

Comment: Also are tere some apps/tools for my Kubuntu 18 on my laptop to see these problems working with my site ?

Comment: You'll have to try each of the vendor trial software/service I'm afraid, can't find an official tool to get a detailed results.